# Apparent @"count:" issue on iPod's with iPhone OS 3.1.3

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, iphone-sdk-3.0, count

I have tracked down a crash users of my app on iPod Touches with iPhone OS 3.1.3 have been having: for some reason, using the "@count:" expression on the CoreData store is causing a crash.  Here's the relevant code:

```
NSExpression *avgExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"average:" arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:keyPathExpression]];
NSExpressionDescription *ed = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[ed setName:@"avgScalar"];
[ed setExpression:avgExpression];
[ed setExpressionResultType:NSFloatAttributeType];

NSExpression *countExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"count:" arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:keyPathExpression]];
NSExpressionDescription *ed2 = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[ed2 setName:@"countScalar"];
[ed2 setExpression:countExpression];
[ed2 setExpressionResultType:NSInteger16AttributeType];

[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:ed,ed2,nil]];
```

When the fetch is performed, I get the following error with the crash:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -constantValue only defined for abstract class.  Define -[NSKeyPathExpression constantValue]!'

If I restrict the fetch to the avgExpression (@"average:"), all works fine.  There's something wonky about the @"count:" expression, so far as I can tell only on iPod Touches with iPhone OS 3.1.3.  Any ideas?

I could alternately perform a full fetch and use key path operators to get the averages and counts I need.  However, I worry this approach would be much more expensive.  Anyone know if it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the best solution for the older OS that I could find, taking only a small performance hit.

1. Execute my fetch request for avgExpression only
2. Clear out the expression part of the request:

   > ```
   >  [request setPropertiesToFetch:nil];
   >
   >  [request setResultType:NSManagedObjectResultType];
   > ```
3. Perform a count-only fetch:

   > ```
   >  [managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:request error:&error];
   > ```

It's clear from working through this issue that the internals of CoreData changed from iOS 3 to iOS 4.  You can see this, for example, by NSLog'ing a property-focused NSFetchRequest object in both OS's.